# is there any way to show pubmed central xml as html

Tags: php, xml, pubmed

I want to show pubmed central xml file as html in a web page. PubMed central xml file looks like this (first part of a xml sample):

```
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Journal Publishing DTD v2.3 20070202//EN" "journalpublishing.dtd">
<article article-type="research-article" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<front>
  <journal-meta>
    <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">JIP</journal-id>
    <journal-title>Journal of International Pharmacology</journal-title>
    <issn pub-type="ppub">2043-835X</issn>
    <publisher>
    <publisher-name>Big Publisher</publisher-name>
    <publisher-loc>USA</publisher-loc>
    </publisher>
  </journal-meta>
  <article-meta>
    <article-id pub-id-type="publisher-id">JIP-3-56</article-id>
```

I tried to use simplexml_load_file, but I could not get anything (probably because of the first line beginning with "article...."). When I changed the first line to

```
<article>
```

simplexml_load_file gives a lot of errors for the rest of the code and again nothing loaded.

I tried the following also, but nothing happened:

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$ajournal = (string)$xmldata->article->front->{journal-meta}->{journal-title};
echo $ajournal;
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML can only work with element nodes, so it loads the document element node.

```
$article = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$ajournal = (string)$article->front->{journal-meta}->{journal-title};
```

But SimpleXML is not very good with namespaces. And the PubMed XML uses XLink and MathML.

More generic you can consider 2 different solutions:

1) If you want to convert XML into another XML or HTML, XSLT was defined for that job. PHP has ext/xslt to support XSLT 1.0 (uses libxslt2). XSLT 2.0 is supported by Saxon/C. But this is not a standard extension.

2) You can use DOM + XPath (or SimpleXML) to read data from XML and use PHP to output the HTML source.

Comment: Yes it works. It would take some time to parse all xml, but I begin to believe that it could be done. Thank you.